# Adding an Arbitrary Link to the Admin Menu?

Tags: menus, themes, admin, wpse-plugin

Is there a way to add a arbitrary hyperlink to the WordPress admin menu (I mean the menu on the left when you log into the admin dashboard)? For example, can one add a link to Google?

In my particular case, I'd like to add a styleguide page for a Wordpress theme I'm working on so I can show the user how different HTML elements are styled with the theme and to demo how to style various things nicely.

This is the code I have so far (*note: it is incomplete*): In *functions.php* I have added a new menu item in the *Appearance* section:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'create_theme_style_page');

function create_theme_style_page() {
  add_theme_page('Theme Styleguide', 'Theme Styleguide', 'administrator', basename(__FILE__),'build_styleguide_page');
}

function build_styleguide_page() {
 echo "Not sure what goes here to redirect admin to a arbitrary url?";
}
```

In `build_styleguide_page()`, attempting to redirect with `header()` gives a error (*Cannot modify header information*).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hi **@Tom**,

If I understand your question correctly you don't so much need to know how to add a link to the menu (it seems you already know that) but instead need to learn how to get your link to redirect correctly, right?

### Redirecting to an External URL from an Admin Menu Item

If so what you need to do is to not use the menu item function but instead *"hook"* WordPress early enough such that it hasn't output anything except possibly HTTP headers. The earliest hook when calling `/wp-admin/themes.php` appears to be `after_setup_theme` and it appears to work well.

#### Use a *"Menu Slug"* So You Can Test for it in a Hook

But to get it to work we first need to modify your call to `add_theme_page` in the `admin_menu` hook / your `create_theme_style_page()` function. We dropped the fifth parameter (the function to call to implement the admin option) because we don't need it, and changed the fourth parameter (the *"menu slug"*) to be `themes.php?goto=build-styleguide-page`.

Although we could have chosen almost literally anything for the fourth parameter, given we are going to redirect I routed to the same page (`themes.php`) as other appearance options for consistency. I also just arbitrarily came up with the name `goto` because WordPress doesn't use it and it seems to make sense for this.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'create_theme_style_page');
function create_theme_style_page() {
  add_theme_page(
    'Theme Styleguide',
    'Theme Styleguide',
    'administrator',
    'themes.php?goto=build-styleguide-page'
  );
}
```

BTW, we got rid of your `build_styleguide_page()` function because we don't need it for this solution.

#### Redirect in  the Earliest Hook for `themes.php`: *`after_setup_theme`*

As our last bit of code we implement our `after_setup_theme` hook in our `redirect_from_admin_menu()` function. We have it test to see if the current page is `themes.php` and to ensure a URL parameter of `goto` was passed on the URL. Then it tests the value of `goto` using a `switch`/`case` statement to see if it has a value of  `'build-styleguide-page'`; if so it redirects to your stated hypothetical e.g. Google otherwise we just redirect back to the admin dashboard:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'redirect_from_admin_menu');
function redirect_from_admin_menu($value) {
  global $pagenow;
  if ($pagenow=='themes.php' && !empty($_GET['goto'])) {
    switch ($_GET['goto']) {
      case 'build-styleguide-page':
        wp_redirect("http://www.google.com");
        break;
      default:
        wp_safe_redirect('/wp-admin/');
        break;
    }
    exit;
  }
}
```

**Notes:**

1. I chose to use the `switch`/`case` statement in the `after_setup_theme` hook / `redirect_from_admin_menu()` function so that it would be easier to add additional `goto` redirects if you need to; just add more case statements.
2. the `wp_redirect()` and `wp_safe_redirect()` functions don't actually terminate; you need to explicit issue an exit statement to get WordPress to stop and not override your redirect.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 22):

If you add your item into the menu by adding it to the `$submenu` array directly you'll avoid the need to do the redirect and be able to use a complete offsite URL as the menu link (i do this myself).

```
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'admin_menu_new_items' );
function admin_menu_new_items() {
    global $submenu;
    $submenu['index.php'][500] = array( 'Menu item name', 'manage_options' , 'http://example.com' ); 
}
```

`index.php` represents the key/link of the parent menu, so in the example i'm basically adding an item to the **Dashboard** menu..

Sure, it's not quite as pretty as using the `add_{type}_page` functions, but it does work-around the fact WordPress prevents off-site URLs in admin menu links..

I use something similar to add my various virtual hosts into the menu, so i can switch to other installations directly from the admin menu (all done with a script, but basically uses a glorified version of the above code).

**NOTE:** If you decide to use the code, just be careful not to assign a key that's in use(the 500 array key in the example code).

**TIP:** You can actually use negative values in the menu keys to, so you can force you menu items to sit before any of the native WordPress items.

Comment: **NOTE:** I think you will need to set that negative key as a string though, ie. `'-5'` and not `-5`, else the key is regarded invalid(i think).. (negative strings works though, if i'm not mistaken)..

Comment: Thanks, sucks that you can't do it with the real functions, but this is a whole lot better than having to add a hook/redirect combo just to have a link.

Comment: This particular answer helped me with my plugin Post Status Menu Items (you can probably guess what it does). Anyway, because I didn't know what other plugins would be adding stuff to what menus, I thought I'd just add that I used `array_push()` to append the menu items to avoid colliding with any other plugins.

Comment: Works like a charm, plus bonus point for using such a small snippet.

Comment: +1. Rather than picking a key and hoping, just grab the last key and increment. For example, when adding a submenu item to the Tools menu: `global $submenu; $key = end(array_keys($submenu['tools.php'])) + 1; $submenu['tools.php'][$key++] = ` etc.

Comment: Thanks alot :) I tried using both Jquery and redirection and had issues. This is perfect.

Comment: I have one question though, how would I add another link? I tried using a multidimensional array, but it is not allowed.

Comment: I purposely avoided the increment approach because i can't always say i want to append or prepend the index, nor did the question have that requirement, but it would be a smart choice if you wanted to programmatically add to the menu.

Comment: To open the link in a new tab /  new page (target="_blank"), read this : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23036664/how-to-open-target-blank-in-a-custom-admin-sub-menu-page

Answer (score 3):

I have achieved same with this:

```
function add_custom_menu_item(){
    add_menu_page( 'Menu Item Title', 'Page Title', 'manage_options', 'page_slug', 'function', 'dashicons-icon', 1 );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_custom_menu_item' );

function custom_menu_item_redirect() {

    $menu_redirect = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : false;

    if($menu_redirect == 'page_slug' ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( home_url('/my-page') );
        exit();
    }

}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'custom_menu_item_redirect', 1 );
```

What you do here is you add menu item and define slug, then on 'admin_init' you check if slug exists and redirect to your desired location.