# Add "external" link to admin menu in the backend

Tags: wp-admin, admin-menu, dashboard

Trying to add a link to my admin menu (dashboard/backend) that leads to the frontend of wordpress, so I basically want a link in the menu that takes me to the blog.

I've found a couple of ways to add new stuff to the admin menu, but I haven't been able to link to the home_url, it seems like the admin menu only is designed to let you link to stuff within the wp-admin. Anyone that have succeeded with this?

Edit:
Tried with this: https://gist.github.com/792b7aa5b695d1092520

```
add_admin_menu_item('Overview',array( 
      'title' => 'View Site',
      'slug' => get_bloginfo('url')
  ));
```

Which gives me the link hxxp://myurl.com/myurl.com
With this plugin (hxxp://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/admin-menu-editor/), I get:
hxxp://myurl.com/wp-admin/www.test.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding an Arbitrary Link to the Admin Menu?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1039/adding-an-arbitrary-link-to-the-admin-menu)

Comment: Since this still shows up in the top search result, and after many hours of searching, here's a way to do it without a redirect. http://www.techedg.com/2014/09/06/5575/a-simple-way-to-add-an-external-link-to-the-wordpress-admin-menu/

Answer (score 7):

you can create a function that redirects to the front-end
like this:

```
function redirect_home_987(){
  wp_redirect( home_url() ); 
  exit;
}
```

and call that function in WordPress default add_menu_page function like this:

```
add_menu_page( 'redirecting', 'View Site', 'read', 'my-top-level-handle', 'redirect_home_987');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly. I've added this to my functions.php now:

add_action('admin_menu', 'add_viewsite');

function add_viewsite() {
add_menu_page( 'redirecting', 'View Site', 'read', 'my-top-level-handle', 'redirect_home_987');
}

// Call this function for a "home" link 
function redirect_home_987(){
  wp_redirect( home_url() ); 
  exit;
}

Which gives me a link that looks like this: http://www.url.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-top-level-handle

Comment: I had the same problem - some of the headers had already been sent.  Tried a few options; the only one that seemed to work (which I'm not really happy with) is combining the above with javascript, like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495478/how-to-redirect-to-different-admin-page-in-wordpress/4594364#4594364)

Comment: It will throw a "headers already sent" error.

Answer (score 1):

The name of site (top left, next to WP logo) links to front-end, is that not sufficient?

Also it would help if you included code that you had tried so far in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I removed the name of the site, since it broke the layout of my customized backend, so I need to implent a link to the front end in the menu instead.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add items to the admin menus that point to external URLs, the menu addition functions do not support this, nor will they allow it.

However, if you attach a callback onto the `admin_menu` hook, you can insert some items yourself manually and totally overcome the non-external URL problem. I do this myself and i'm quite surprised noone has already pointed out the issue with external menu links.

I provided an example when answering [Adding an Arbitrary Link to the Admin Menu?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1039/adding-an-arbitrary-link-to-the-admin-menu/3831#3831)

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: In fact, this question seems to be an exact duplicate of this one. So it got my vote to close it!

Comment: @Jan Fabry - I was thinking that when i linked to the other question so i've also voted to close as duplicate (the user should also have the answer he/she is looking for now, so closing need not be considered a bad thing).

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'example_admin_menu');

/**
* add external link to Tools area
*/
function example_admin_menu() {
    global $submenu;
    $url = 'http://www.example.com/';
    $submenu['tools.php'][] = array('Example', 'manage_options', $url);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

just add ../ as slug prefix:

```
add_admin_menu_item('Overview',array( 
  'title' => 'View Site',
  'slug' => '../slug'          // relative url
));
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?