# Admin top level menu, pointing to an external url

Tags: wp-admin, admin, menus, admin-menu, dashboard

I want to create a entirely new top level menu in the admin menu section, and have that be an external link, is this even possible with the current system?

The solution that t31os provides in this thread works if you put the link as a submenu under, for example, the dashboard. But this is not what I want to do.

[Adding an Arbitrary Link to the Admin Menu?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1039/adding-an-arbitrary-link-to-the-admin-menu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add your custom item into `$menu` instead of `$submenu`.

Use here as a reference for parent menu structure.
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-admin/menu.php

Eg.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'admin_menu_wpse32975' );
function admin_menu_wpse32975() {
    global $menu;
    $menu[9999] = array( __('My Menu'), 'manage_options', 'http://www.google.com', '', 'open-if-no-js menu-top', '', 'div' );
}
```

Comment: I wanted to use this code for another project, but I just now realized that using this piece of code, I don't get the "current" class when the link is active (like you do on regular admin menu items). I really need this for a coherent styling in this project. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: How would that work exactly? Once you click that link you should no longer be on the WordPress site(if the link the points to an external URL).

Comment: Oh, doh. Was a bit tired when I wrote that. I'm now using the code to create a "shortcut" to a dashboard url. It's a direct link to a submenu item: http://pastebin.com/q89sAVTi

Comment: If you're going to point it to an interal page use the proper menu functions, `add_menu_page` or `add_submenu_page` and it will deal with marking an item as active/current for you.

Comment: I thought so too, but either I'm doing it wrong or it doesnt work: http://pastebin.com/PeiFnW6N There's a link but it doesn't show if it's active/current.

Comment: Works fine for me, inside a callback on `admin_menu` and providing the `add_menu_page` call a callback(because `edit.php?page=post` is not a WordPress page). [Pastebin of my test code](http://pastebin.com/xsuUfM94).

Answer (score 0):

For external link this will work using the `add_menu_page` or `add_submenu_page`. Just change `http://www.google.com` below to your desired link:

```
function add_custom_menu_item_external_url(){
    add_menu_page( 'My Posts', 'My Posts', 'manage_options', 'link-to-google', 'custom_menu_item_redirect', 'dashicons-admin-links', 1 );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_custom_menu_item_external_url' );


function custom_menu_item_redirect_external_link() {
        $menu_redirect = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : false;
        if($menu_redirect == 'link-to-google' ) {
            header('Location: http://www.google.com');
            exit();
        }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'custom_menu_item_redirect_external_link', 1 );
```

For internal link use below and change home_url() or for something like the logged in [author page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/207148/43806) check that out:

```
function add_custom_admin_menu_page_home_url(){
    add_menu_page( 'Home', 'Home', 'manage_options', 'home-redirect', 'custom_menu_item_redirect_home_url', 'dashicons-admin-links', 1 );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_custom_admin_menu_page_home_url' );


function custom_menu_item_redirect_home_url() {
        $menu_redirect = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : false;
        if($menu_redirect == 'home-redirect' ) {
            wp_safe_redirect( home_url() );
            exit();
        }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'custom_menu_item_redirect_home_url', 1 );
```