# Add Top-Level Menu that opens URL

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions

Below code adds `My Page` button in Admin Menu. It will take you to your author page when you click on it. However, it also opens up new page(Empty page).

I want it to just take you to author page and do not open a new page in backend.
How do I achieve that? I also make this menu show up for all user roles(it only shows up on Admin role now)

I know my code is wrong. Please let me know if you have any suggestion to write it better.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_my_custom_menu' );

function add_my_custom_menu() {
    //add an item to the menu
    add_menu_page (
        'My Page',
        'My Page',
        'manage_options',
        'my-page',
        'see_my_page_function',
        'dashicons-controls-play',
        '100'
    );
}

function see_my_page_function() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    ?>
    <script>
        url = "<?php echo get_site_url().'/author/'.$current_user->user_login.'/'; ?>";
        window.open(url, '_blank');
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the second parameter in window.open and just have it as `window.open(url)`

Comment: Thank you for the comment! That did not work. Some how it acts exactly the same with `_blank`. I would like to open url on new tab anyways tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've experimented with various solutions or workarounds proposed elsewhere on this site - for instance here: [Adding an Arbitrary Link to the Admin Menu?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1039/adding-an-arbitrary-link-to-the-admin-menu/3831#3831) and this one here: http://www.techedg.com/2014/09/06/5575/a-simple-way-to-add-an-external-link-to-the-wordpress-admin-menu/

*All of the solutions that I tested that worked included that behavior of adding an unwanted blank admin page.* I'm not sure that there is not some solution buried somewhere - or some trick you can use to close the page after it's been opened! - but the indication is that WP does not want you to do what you want to do.

I think the cleanest solution you can try is to add a link directly to *a submenu*. You'll find some indications on the pages I linked above.

You might also consider simply adding the link - or the re-direct - via the blank page: So, in other words, cooperate with WordPress load the page, and work it from there: Add a link to the author page that also appears there, initiate some other process, point to the user-profile page, or incorporate other functions for editing the user's profile information.

To answer your minor question, to make the link available to all users, use 'read' instead of 'manage_options' as the third, capabilities variable under the add_menu_page() array.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I believe you have a typo on "For make the link available to all users", I tried `read` and it worked :)

Comment: Fixed! If a better answer doesn't show up, please consider marking my answer as an answer - at least on the part that's answerable as asked. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, this will automatically open author url of logged in author:

```
function add_custom_menu_item_logged_in_author(){
    add_menu_page( 'My Posts', 'My Posts', 'manage_options', 'author-redirect', 'custom_menu_item_redirect', 'dashicons-nametag', 1 );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_custom_menu_item_logged_in_author' );


function custom_menu_item_redirect_logged_in_author() {
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        // change $my_redirect_url if accessing a different url other than author page
        $my_redirect_url = get_author_posts_url($current_user->ID); 
        $menu_redirect = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : false;

        if($menu_redirect == 'author-redirect' ) {
            wp_safe_redirect( $my_redirect_url );
            exit();
        }

}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'custom_menu_item_redirect_logged_in_author', 1 );
```