# Create Logout Link Wordpress Admin Menu

Tags: php, functions, admin-menu

I'm looking at creating a Logout link in the Wordpress admin menu that when clicked the user is logged out immediately.

I don't want the Logout link to be a submenu of an existing menu, I just want it to be the last item that appears on the menu.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What research have you done so far. Please add the code that you have so far

Comment: Hi Pieter, I've looked at this - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51157/add-logout-button-on-admin-side-menu but this redirects to a page with a quote in the meantime. What @TheDeadMagic has created is great, except I'm wanting the logout ini the admin side panel to the left, not the top admin toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the awesome [`WP_Admin_Bar`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Admin_Bar) & hook in with `admin_bar_menu`:

```
/**
 * Add a "Log out" link directly to the admin bar.
 * 
 * @link    http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/141446/1685
 * 
 * @param   WP_Admin_Bar    $wp_admin_bar
 */
function wpse_141446_admin_bar_logout( $wp_admin_bar ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $wp_admin_bar->add_menu(
            array(
                'id'     => 'my-log-out',
                'parent' => 'top-secondary',
                'title'  => __( 'Log out' ),
                'href'   => wp_logout_url(),
            )
        );
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wpse_141446_admin_bar_logout', 100 );
```

Comment: That's excellent! But... how do I get it in the admin menu on the side?

Comment: Just add `'parent' => 'top-secondary'` (see revised answer).

Comment: Hmm, thanks for this, but I mean the sidebar admin panel, the one with Pages, Posts, Media, Links etc.