# Add Submenu Link in add_submenu_page That Opens in a New Window

Tags: plugin-development, menus

How can I add a sub menu link using [add_submenu_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) that will open a new window (`target="_blank"`) instead of opening in the current one (default behavior)?

Comment: A good question :) Any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to be solved:

- with an unconventional submenu manipulation, provided by @t31os in [this Answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/3831/12615)
- and some jQuery

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpse_66020_admin_menu_new_item' );
add_action( 'admin_head', 'wpse_66020_add_jquery' );

function wpse_66020_admin_menu_new_item() 
{
    global $submenu;
    $submenu['index.php'][500] = array( 
                                    '<div id="wpse-66020">Go to WPSE</div>'
                                ,   'manage_options' 
                                ,   'https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/' 
                                ); 
}

function wpse_66020_add_jquery() 
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready( function($) {   
            $('#wpse-66020').parent().attr('target','_blank');  
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

---

**Resulting in this:**

[image: submenu with _blank target]
<sup>click to enlarge</sup>