# Is possible to create a custom link that creates a post that's already categorized?

Tags: posts, categories, admin, admin-menu

I know this is not really a coding question but here goes.
So is it possible to add a link to the WordPress Admin Sidebar that links to a New Post page that is automatically categorized as a category "team"?

I can add the sidebar link easily with this code

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_team_page' );
function register_team_page(){
    add_menu_page( 'Team Menu Title', 'Team menu', 'publish_posts', '#link-goes-here', '', "", 6 );
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to properly link to a New Posts page with the category "team" preselected.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding an Arbitrary Link to the Admin Menu?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1039/adding-an-arbitrary-link-to-the-admin-menu)

Comment: ^^ The solution by @t3los is the one want I believe : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/3831/21376

Comment: No. The code I posted above does essentially the same thing and is able to add a link to the admin menu. I am trying to figure how to make that link take you a new page with a category pre-selected.

Comment: I don't believe the two are entirely equivalent and the approach in the other question strikes me as the better way to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

So show all posts in one category I can do something like this

> edit.php?filter-posts=category_id_number

Replace the category_id_number with the ID number of the category like 3.

But not sure for the new page link

Comment: this is not an answer, edit your question to add additional information.